# Error: Unknown domain: stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

Just got an error while opening stackoverflow.com:

> [image]

> Fastly error: unknown domain: stackoverflow.com. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.
>
> Details: cache-ams21055-AMS

It seems that the problem on VPN side that I'm using.

Additionally I noticed that the link to Mod Q&A was changed from stackoverflowteams.com to stackoverflow.com. It redirects to https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/moderators/questions in result.

> [image]

Might this be a source for that "unknown domain" error?

Comment: Also on MSO: [Fastly error: unknown domain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426682)

Comment: Looks like having two CDN's is causing such issues, so hopefully when the switch to new provider is completed it will not happen again.